# How to display the value without the key after JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to display the value of a key after using JSON.stringify to collect form data and put into JSON. Now I need the value of a specific key within from this json file but I get the key/value pair:

> {"KEY":"KM8IJM12D56U303366"}

Currently my code to display this is:

```
const onSubmit = async data => {

    // How to get specific data from stringify
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, ["KEY"]);
    alert(jsonString);
    notify();
};
```

I have tried using getItem() but that seems to only work with local storage. Is there a solution where I can just directly access the value of KEY after JSON.stringify()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to `JSON.parse()` it back to an object to access keys and values. After you apply `stringify()`, it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, My first suggestion over this would be, Go with the *data* as Object, don't stringify that.

```
const onSubmit = async data => {

    // If data is not a Stringify Object:
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data.key);
    alert(jsonString);
    notify();

    //********

    // If data is a Stringify Object:
    var jsonString = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(jsonString.key);
    notify();


    
};
```

But If you want to go with a string:

```
const onSubmit = async data => {
    // If you want to use only the Key as a string, go with the line below
    var jsonString = data.key.toString();

    // Else Directly access your key by the below line.
    var jsonString = data.key;

    alert(jsonString);
    notify();
};
```